# How do I cut every nth row and paste it on every nth row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, cut-and-paste

Let's say I have a list of cities at rows 1, 4, 7... 3n - 2

And let's say I have a list of states at rows 3, 6, 9... 3n

The cities and states are in the same column

How do I cut the states so that at rows 1, 4, 7... 3n - 2 the information of City, State shows up?

For example,

#### Input:

```
Richmond
Virginia
New York City
New York
```

#### Output:

```
Richmond, Virginia
New York City, New York
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with VBA or formulas? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've never used excel before, so far I'm just cutting and pasting every third line

Comment: I looked at almost all excel formulas and it doesn't seem like you can manipulate data by cutting and pasting

Comment: @DanielChristl, if you are comfortable with VBA(Macro) then I can suggest one simple method to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Your description does not match your example, so you've received answers that don't match your description.  Please make your question internally consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas never copy/paste, but they can manipulate strings. In a different column, enter this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("A" & (ROW(C1)-1)*2+1),", ",INDIRECT("A" & (ROW(C1))*2+1))
```

Then populate it down the column.

Assumptions: Your data is in column `A` and the formula is in Column `C`

Answer (score 0):

**Check the Screen Shot:**

[image]

*You can use the following Formula which generates effect like concatenation :*

```
=OFFSET(L2,(ROW(L1)*1)-1,0)& ", "&OFFSET(L3,(ROW(L1)*1)-1,0)
```

**N.B.**

- After you write the Formula in the desire cell, fill it downwards.
- Adjust the cell address as per your need.